# how to add substring into a string

Tags: javascript

I have a url and i need to enter a port number to the url. 
the url is not a valid url. 
here is few show cases :

```
https://example.com_users/param/param/param -  https://example.com_users:8080/param/param/param
http://example.co_setting/param/param/param -  http://example.co_settings:1000/param/param/param
http://example.co_setting-  http://example.co_settings:1000
```

```js
const addPort = (url,port) =>{
    
    combined =  ???????? // how to combian them
    return combined 
}
```

Comment: where u tried. stackoverfow is not a free code service

Comment: Try using google for these types of questions.

Comment: i try to google it all ready...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```js
const addPort = (url, port) => 
    url.replace(/^(https?:\/\/)?([^/]*)(\/.*)?$/, '$1' + '$2:' + port + '$3');

console.log(addPort('http://www.example.com/full/url/with/param', '8080'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var urlstring = 'https://example.com_users/param/param/param';
var port = ':8080';
var allparts = urlstring.split('//');
var last = allparts[1];
var alllastparts = last.split('/');;
alllastparts[0] = alllastparts[0]+port;

alert(allparts[0]+ '//' + alllastparts.join('/'));
console.log(allparts[0]+ '//' + alllastparts.join('/'));
```

Comment: i dont have : in my strings. i need to add in the function